# R - ggplot scale_x_date incorrect dates in graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created graph in R with this code:

```
x <- data.frame(
  "date" = seq(Sys.Date()-120, Sys.Date(), "weeks"), 
  "amount" = seq(1:18),
  stringsAsFactors = F)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(x, aes(x=date, y=amount)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week", date_labels = "%d-%m-%y")
```

Everything is fine except the fact that my dataframe starts with date 2019-02-17 but graphs starts with date 2019-02-11 (similar issue at the end of the graph). How to make my graph starting with proper date (2019-02-17)?

Comment: You could use `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`. The general rule is that use `geom_col()` when the values are already present in the data, like they are in your data. Furthermore though, why not use `geom_line()` when visualizing time series data?

Another issue seems to be that you want to use Sunday as a start of the week. By default `scale_x_date()`'s `date_breaks = "1 week"` uses Monday as the start of the week so `2019-02-18` (Monday) will be the first label unless you use a custom scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```r
ggplot(x, aes(x=date, y=amount)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week", date_labels = "%d-%m-%y", expand = c(0,0))
```

`ggplot` 'pads' your data for displaying reasons.